# .Net 4.5 killed my TPL, now what?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, .net-4.5

Exhibit 1: some code wrapping an Async (not `async`!) network call into a `Task`

```
public static Task<byte[]> GetAsync(IConnection connection, uint id)
{
    ReadDataJob jobRDO = new ReadDataJob();

    //No overload of FromAsync takes 4 extra parameters, so we have to wrap
    // Begin in a Func so that it looks like it takes no parameters except 
    // callback and state
    Func<AsyncCallback, object, IAsyncResult> wrapped = (callback, state) =>
                jobRDO.Begin(connection, 0, 0, id, callback, state);

    return Task<byte[]>.Factory.FromAsync(wrapped, ar =>
    {
        ErrorCode errorCode;
        UInt32 sError;
        UInt32 attribute;
        byte[] data = new byte[10];
        jobRDO.End(out errorCode, out sError, out attribute, out data);
        if(error != ErrorCode.NO_ERROR)  throw new Exception(error.ToString());
        return data;
    }, jobRDO);
}
```

Installing .Net 4.5 (not pointing VS at it, nor recompiling) stops this working. The callback is never invoked.

Any ideas what could be causing this, and otherwise, what I can do to try and further narrow down the root cause of the problem or work around it?

Comment: Found the last item in this, but I'm not sure how to interpret it: [FromAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh367887%28v=VS.110%29.aspx#core): *"The IAsyncResult implementation must complete synchronously and its CompletedSynchronously property must return true for the resulting task to complete."* (last item in table)

Comment: I doubt this is a framework version issue. Are you using any network debugging tool? You should check if it's doing at least the request. I've done a lot of async wrapping with .net 4.5 and no problem!

Comment: Haha, check this out, if you follow the link in my previous comment, then click on "CompleteSynchronously", the text reads: *"Most implementers of the IAsyncResult interface will not use this property and should return false."*

Comment: So I had luck in my wrappings as all of them return true

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Re-edit**: I've exchanged several emails with [Stephen Toub](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/toub/). Below I attempt to merge my original answer and his answers into a coherent whole.

**tl;dr** to work around this, force `CompleteSynchronously` to always return false (*caveat non-lector*).

---

### MSDN documentation of .Net 4.5 'breaking' changes

Immediately after posting this question, I clicked through to a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14424221/what-other-silent-changes-did-happen-from-net-frameworkf-v-4-0-to-4-5?rq=1), and ended up at ["Application Compatibility in the .NET Framework 4.5"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh367887%28v=VS.110%29.aspx#core), which has this to say about `FromAsync`:

> **Change**: The `IAsyncResult` implementation must complete synchronously and its `CompletedSynchronously` property must return **true**
>   for the resulting task to complete.
>
> **Impact**: The resulting task will not complete if an `IAsyncResult` implementation does not complete synchronous execution but its
>   `CompletedSynchronously` property returns True.

Ironically, (or infuriatingly), the page for [`CompletedSynchronously`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iasyncresult.completedsynchronously.aspx) states:

> **Notes to Implementers**: Most implementers of the `IAsyncResult` interface will not use this property and should return **false**.

---

### Stephen Toub clarified this with the following:

> The table at
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh367887%28v=VS.110%29.aspx#core,
>   and specifically the description of the “Change”, is wrong (...).
>
> There was a change in .NET 4.5 to `FromAsync`, but it wasn’t that all
>   `IAsyncResult.CompletedSynchronously` implementations must return true:
>   that wouldn’t make any sense.  The change was that `FromAsync` actually
>   looks at the `IAsyncResult’s CompletedSynchronously` now (it didn’t look
>   at it at all in .NET 4), and thus it expects it to be accurate.  As
>   such, if you had a buggy `IAsyncResult` implementation, `FromAsync` might
>   still have worked in .NET 4, whereas with .NET 4.5, it’s less likely
>   to work with a buggy implementation.
>
> Specifically, it’s ok if `IAsyncResult.CompletedSynchronously` returns
>   `false`.  However, if it returns `true`, the `IAsyncResult` must have in
>   fact completed synchronously.  If `CompletedSynchronously` returns
>   `true` but the `IAsyncResult` has not completed, you have a bug that needs
>   to be fixed, and it’s likely that the `Task` returned from `FromAsync`
>   will not complete correctly.
>
> The change was made for performance reasons.

---

### Returning to my problem code

Here is his very helpful analysis, which I include in full as it will probably be useful for other implementers of `IAsyncResult`:

> The problem appears to be that the library you’re using has a very
>   faulty implementation of `IAsyncResult`; in particular, it’s
>   implementing `CompletedSynchronously` incorrectly.  Here’s their
>   implementation:
>
> ```
> public bool CompletedSynchronously
> {
>     get { return _isCompleted; }
> }
> public bool IsCompleted
> {
>     get { return _isCompleted; }
> }
> ```
>
> Their `_isCompleted` field indicates whether the asynchronous operation
>   has completed, which is fine, and it’s fine to return this from
>   `IsCompleted`, since that property is meant to indicate whether the
>   operation completed or not.  But `CompletedSynchronously` can’t just
>   return that same field: `CompletedSynchronously` needs to return whether
>   the operation completed synchronously, i.e. whether it completed
>   during the call to `BeginXx`, and it must always return the same value
>   for a given `IAsyncResult` instance.
>
> Consider the standard pattern for how
>   `IAsyncResult.CompletedSynchronously` is used.  Its purpose is to allow
>   the caller of `BeginXx` to continue doing the follow-on work, rather
>   than having the callback due the work.  This is particularly important
>   for avoiding stack dives (imagine a long sequence of asynchronous
>   operations that all actually completed synchronously: if the callbacks
>   handled all of the work, then each callback would initiate the next
>   operation, whose callback would initiate the next operation, but
>   because they were completing synchronously, their callbacks would also
>   be invoked synchronously as part of the `BeginXx` methods, so each call
>   would get deeper and deeper on the stack, until it potentially
>   overflowed):
>
> ```
> IAsyncResult ar = BeginXx(…, delegate(IAsyncResult iar) =>
> {
>     if (iar.CompletedSynchronously) return;
>     … // do the completion work, like calling EndXx and using its result
> }, …);
> if (ar.CompletedSynchronously)
> {
>     … // do the completion work, like calling EndXx and using its result
> }
> ```
>
> Note that both the caller and the callback use the same
>   `CompletedSynchronously` property to determine which of them runs the
>   callback.  As such, `CompletedSynchronously` must always return the same
>   value for this particular instance.  If it doesn’t, erroneous behavior
>   can easily result.  For example, their implementation has
>   `CompletedSynchronously` returning the equivalent of `IsCompleted`.  So
>   imagine the following sequence of events:
>
> - `BeginXx` is called and initiates the async operation
> - `BeginXx` returns to its caller, which checks `CompletedSynchronously`, which is false, because the operation hasn’t
>     completed yet.
> - Now the operation completes and the callback is invoked.  The callback sees that `CompletedSynchronously` is true, and so doesn’t
>     do any of the subsequent work, because it assumes the caller did it.
> - And now no one’s run or will run the callback.
>
> In short, the library has a bug.  If you changed
>   `CompletedSynchronously` to return true, you masked this problem, but
>   you likely caused another: if the caller (in your case, `FromAsync`)
>   thinks that the operation has already completed, it’ll proceed to
>   immediately call the `EndXx` method, which will block until the async
>   operation has completed, so you’ve turned your asynchronous operations
>   into synchronous ones.  Have you tried just always returning false
>   from `CompletedSynchronously` instead of always returning true?

Comment: Hi Folks, This should only affects code that has buggy implementation of IAsyncResult. Please contact us on netfx45compat at Microsoft dot com if you are hit by this issue. We would like to understand your scenario.